# Ask SSH passphrase only once for "chained SSH"

Tags: linux, mac, ssh, git

I have a master running Ubuntu and a Slave running Mac OSX 10.6.8. I set up the SSH keys. When connecting to the GIT repo directly from Slave, everything works well and I am not asked to enter a passphrase.

However, when I first SSHed from Master to Slave and then try to connect to the GIT repo, I am asked to enter the passphrase at each command. What should I do to solve this?

**Summary**

**terminal**`-->`**Slave**`--SSH (a)-->`**GIT repo** ==>> NO passphrase asked in (a)

**terminal**`-->`**Master**`--SSH-->`**Slave**`--SSH (a)-->`**GIT repo** ==>> passphrase asked in (a)

Comment: In the second case, your terminal doesn't know about the `ssh-agent` that stores the SSH key (therefore not requiring to type the passphrase again). See also http://superuser.com/questions/141044/sharing-the-same-ssh-agent-among-multiple-login-sessions

Comment: Excellent, it seems to be working! Now, I need to find a way to tell Jenkins to use the "-A" flag;) Thanks!