# How to save ssh identity settings in Snow Leopard?

Tags: macos, ssh, ssh-agent

I'm using ssh settings from my work machine on laptop at home for unattended git repository connection. I've copied private and public keys and use ssh-agent w/ ssh-add identity command. Is there any way to save this settings permanently? Every time after reboot i need to execute above commands again that is kinda annoying. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Add the ssh private keys to your keychain.

```
ssh-add -K /path/to/private/ssh/key
```

More [here](https://superuser.com/questions/88470/how-to-use-mac-os-x-keychain-with-ssh-keys).