# MacOS Keychain Access holds on to SSH passphrase indefinitely

Tags: macos, ssh, security, rsa, keychain

For the sake of convenience, I would like MacOS to hold on to my RSA passphrase, but not indefinitely (for the sake of security).  I believe SSH will use **Keychain Access** with this SSH configuration

```
Host *
     UseKeychain true
```

And I believe it will use **ssh-agent** with this configuration:

```
Host *
     AddKeysToAgent yes
```

A few questions:

1. It seems like there are two options: **ssh-agent** or **Keychain Access**.  If you need the convenience of *temporarily* storing passphrases, what is the standard?
2. How can I identify and clear the passphrase for my default private key in Keychain Access?  I see an unnamed private key, but I don't want to delete it without knowing for sure that it is my stored SSH key
3. What is the best option if I want to regularly clear any private key passphrases?  I could use **ssh-add -D** under a cron job

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before we start, let's clarify a couple of points:

- macOS will allow you to store the private key **passphrases** in the macOS keychain.
- ssh-agent (on macOS or any system) holds the **decrypted** private key **in memory**.

The distinction is important to answer your questions.

> 1. It seems like there are two options: ssh-agent or Keychain Access.

Not exactly.  See clarification above.  If you use the `UseKeychain yes` directive in your `~/.ssh/config`, then any program connecting to the `ssh-agent` socket will allow `ssh-agent` to reach into the Keychain for the passphrase to decrypt your private key.  If you **also** use the the `AddKeysToAgent yes` directive, then that decrypted key will be stored in the agent for future use.  Also useful to [see another related question](https://superuser.com/questions/88470/how-to-use-mac-os-x-keychain-with-ssh-keys).

> ... If you need the convenience of temporarily storing passphrases, what is the standard?

There is (to my knowledge) no way to have macOS store the passphrases **temporarily**.  However, a partially satisfying solution for nearly the same effect can be had -- see answer to question 3 below.

> 2. How can I identify and clear the passphrase for my default private key in Keychain Access? I see an unnamed private key, but I don't want to delete it without knowing for sure that it is my stored SSH key.

If you open Keychain Access on your Mac, and search for `ssh`, you likely won't see your ssh key passphrase.  Starting with macOS Sierra (10.12), Apple moved which keychain `ssh` keys were stored.  To see it, you need to select *"View >> Show Invisible Items"* and then ssh key passphrase entries will be visible.

Chances are the "unnamed private key" you were seeing was some other RSA (or DSA) key.

> 3. What is the best option if I want to regularly clear any private key passphrases?  I could use `ssh-add -D` under a cron job.

While you could put `ssh-add -D` into a cron job, and it probably would do some of what you want, it would not remove the **passphrases** from the keychain. It would only clear the memory of the running `ssh-agent` of all **decrypted** private keys.  If you have `UseKeychain yes` in your config, `ssh-agent` will happily re-decrypt the key again next time it is needed (see above answer to question 1).

One alternative to satisfy your implied desire to not have decrypted keys available all the time is to turn off both `UseKeychain` and `AddKeysToAgent`, as in:

```
Host *
  UseKeychain no
  AddKeysToAgent no
```

Then, manually add keys to your running `ssh-agent` with limited lifetimes using the `-t <lifetime>` option to `ssh-add`, as in:

```
ssh-add -t 4h ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

That will add your (default) RSA key to the agent with a lifetime of 4 hours.  After four hours, the key will be removed automatically.

As far as I know, there is no directive for your user `~/.ssh/config` to specify the default lifetime of any key added to the agent, nor is there a way in the system `sshd_config`.  However, there **may** be a way to tell macOS to start the agent with a default lifetime using the `-t <lifetime>` option.  For the intrepid, the launch agent plist file is stored in `/System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.openssh.ssh-agent.plist`.

Another [older, possibly still relevant approach](https://www.dribin.org/dave/blog/archives/2007/11/28/securing_ssh_agent/) locks they keychain while sleeping.